# Project to NAD83 (epsg:26912) with projectRaster - gives epsg:2152

Tags: raster, r, coordinate-system, nad83

I am working with some Landsat 8 images from the U.S. Geological Survey (USGS) Earth Resources Observation and Science (EROS) Center. I am processing the images in R, and after masking the clouds, I want to project from the following CRS `"+proj=utm +zone=12 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"` (as they are defined in the original data) to `NAD 1983 UTM 12N`.

I apply de following function (because I have 70 images):

```
test <- raster(xmn=220785, xmx=455115, ymn=4029285, ymx=4267815, res=30)
crs(test) <- "+proj=utm +zone=12 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"

vals <- 1:ncell(test)
test <- setValues(test, vals)

pred.list <- list(test)
names(pred.list) <- c("test")

NAD83proj <- "+init=epsg:26912 +proj=utm +zone=12 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"

projtoNAD1983 <- function(x) {
    l8_NAD1983 <- list()
    for (i in 1:length(x)) { 
        print(i)
        l8_NAD1983[[i]] <- projectRaster(from="+proj=utm +zone=12 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0",crs=NAD83proj, filename= paste0(names(pred.list[i]), "_nad83.tif"), type="GTiff", overwrite=T)
    }
    return(l8_NAD1983)
    gc()
}

test_nad1983 <- projtoNAD1983(pred.list)
```

But the output GTiff has a deprecated crs: `"+proj=utm +zone=12 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"`

I do not know what I do wrong. My version of `rgdal` is 1,1-1, `GDAL` 1.11.2 (2015/02/10).

Should I just assign the projection `epsg:26912` manually?

Comment: Landsat 8 has either 15 or 30 m resolution. The differences between WGS84 and NAD83 are much less than that so don't bother reprojecting it. Just assign/define EPSG:26912 if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Please always simplify your example to allow focusing on the essence of your question (no need for a function, or a loop here). It had an error (the `from` argument is wrong). I also made `test` smaller.

```
test <- raster(xmn=220785, xmx=224595, ymn=4263885, ymx=4267815, res=30)
crs(test) <- "+proj=utm +zone=12 +datum=WGS84 +units=m"
values(test) <- 1:ncell(test)
NAD83proj <- "+init=epsg:26912 +proj=utm +zone=12 +datum=NAD83 +units=m"
x <- projectRaster(from=test, crs=NAD83proj)
```

So you get

```
crs(x)
# CRS arguments:
# +proj=utm +zone=12 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

Which, I think, is the same thing as what you want, expressed differently. Somehow it states the ellipsoid but not the datum. Perhaps because of using an epsg code. I do not know what that code stands for --- I know you can look that up -- but why make things opaque and not simply ask for what you want:

```
NAD83proj2 <-"+proj=utm +zone=12 +datum=NAD83 +units=m"
y <- projectRaster(from=test, crs=NAD83proj2)
crs(y)

# CRS arguments:
#  +proj=utm +zone=12 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

Whether it is a good idea to do all this (see mkennedy's comment) is another matter. Note tha tin both cases you have: `+towgs84=0,0,0`, i.e., no difference.